# True false expression errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops

I am trying to build a module that will apply only in conditions when the requirements of the statement are satisfied. In this case if I specify the value for "var.enable_standbyinfra" that is true then the module will be created. I want to understand if I am approaching this type of method wrong or get on the right path

```
 iam_instance_profile_standby = "${var.enable_standbyinfra == "true" ?
 module.aem_disp_a_standby_iam.aws_iam_instance_profile_id : 0 }"
```

and further used in:

```
iam_instance_profile   = "${local.iam_instance_profile_standby}"
```

The result is that I get an error when running terraform and the error is:

```
local.iam_instance_profile_standby: At column 3, line 1: true and false expression types must match; have type list and type int in:

${var.enable_standbyinfra == "true" ? module.aem_disp_a_standby_iam.aws_iam_instance_profile_id : 0 }
```

So the final result I want to get to is that if I specify that "var.enable_standbyinfra" is equal to true the resource is created. If set to "false" I want it to be skipped.

If I posted it wrong without a clear understanding please accept my excuses I am not a expert user in stackoverflow still learning

Comment: Can you reproduce as a [mcve] so we can see more clearly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

This argument should be a string, so:

```
var.enable_standbyinfra == "true" ?
module.aem_disp_a_standby_iam.aws_iam_instance_profile_id : ""
```